# gcc: segmentation fault when compiling with nostdlib

Tags: c, gcc, linker, segmentation-fault

I'm experimenting with entry points and got a segfault.

prog.c:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

compiling and linking with:

```
 gcc -Wall prog.c -nostdlib -c -o prog.o
 ld prog.o -e main -o prog.out
```

objdump:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
0 .text         0000000b  00000000004000b0  00000000004000b0  000000b0  2**2
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
1 .eh_frame     00000038  00000000004000c0  00000000004000c0  000000c0  2**3
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
2 .comment      0000001c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000000f8  2**0
              CONTENTS, READONLY

Disassembly of section .text:
00000000004000b0 <main>:
 4000b0:    55                      push   %rbp
 4000b1:    48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 4000b4:    b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 4000b9:    5d                      pop    %rbp
 4000ba:    c3                      retq
```

Valgrind output:

```
 Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

retq takes the return address from the top of the stack and executes from there... problem is that according to the way Linux executes binaries, the number of arguments is on the stack and execution is transferred to address 0x1 (if no arguments are given)

set some dummy arguments with gdb (set args x y z)

you can compile and link with debug info (-g) and then use gdb
set a breakpoint on the retq instruction (br *0x4000ba) and run the program

execute the final instruction and observe the SIGSEGV address correspond to the number of arguments + 1

the program should exit with a system call, not retq

see
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/08/13/how-statically-linked-programs-run-on-linux/
for some useful background info

Comment: Thanks, but how can I exit() without including stdlib?

Comment: I managed to exit using a syscall with assembly, but I wonder if there is a pure c solution. http://pastebin.com/nteHpCmZ

Comment: @Dimid A "pure C" solution can not exist because you *must* execute the `exit` system call, and there is no way to do that in pure C.